# is there a way to get screen space reflections working in a-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

anyone know how to get ssr working in a-frame, i have tried a few methods but nothing seems to work.

i have tried following the official doc. but this just results in very weird behaviour and there are no reflections. acts more like fog tbh.
https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/components/reflection.html#properties

i have also tried this https://npm.io/package/aframe-effects but again i cant seem to get it to work, it seems to support some effects but not ssr.

any help would be greatly appreciated